# java.net.socketexception connection reset by peer socket write error While deploying war on Tomcat7 through Jenkins (Using Maven)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jenkins, tomcat7, maven-3

I am trying to deploy a maven based web project on tomcat7 through Jenkins. When i try to execute maven goal "mvn tomcat7:deploy" from my command prompt, it works all fine and deploy the application on running tomcat7 instance.
Now i set up a Job on Jenkins for the same Projects and getting socket error. Below is my code and the stacktrace from Jenkins console.

Entry in POM.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>Tomcat7Server</server>
            <path>/ElecnorMPR</path>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Apache Maven Settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>Tomcat7Server</id>
  <username>tomcat</username>
  <password>tomcat</password>
</server>
```

Already defined the users in tomcat-user.xml.

```
    [DEBUG] Connection 0.0.0.0:51036<->127.0.0.1:8080 closed
[DEBUG] Closing the connection.
[DEBUG] Connection 0.0.0.0:51036<->127.0.0.1:8080 closed
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[DEBUG] Connection reset by peer: socket write error

    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.write(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:73)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:880)
        at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:331)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
        at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:325)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[INFO] Retrying request
[DEBUG] Reopening the direct connection.
[DEBUG] Connecting to localhost:8080
[DEBUG] Attempt 2 to execute request
[DEBUG] Sending request: PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2FElecnorMPR HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG]  >> "PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2FElecnorMPR HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "User-Agent: Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin/2.2[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Content-Length: 33093536[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Authorization: Basic dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2FElecnorMPR HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] >> User-Agent: Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin/2.2
[DEBUG] >> Content-Length: 33093536
[DEBUG] >> Host: localhost:8080
[DEBUG] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] >> Authorization: Basic dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FElecnorMPR
```

Comment: Can anyone please answer this soon..

Comment: Did you get solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I also faced this error while deploying war in heroku. But after redeploying it successfully deployed

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the maven repository that is being used it is possible that a [version policy](https://community.sonatype.com/t/400-repository-version-policy-snapshot-does-not-allow-version-3-0-0/4053) or an [existing artifact](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/GAP-169) is causing the repository to close the connection. This may happen with or without a proper error message.

My issue was caused by the former using Gradle and Nexus. It did only issue the proper error in a different project.